# can this be considered duplicate code?

Tags: java, inversion-of-control

This is my first post here, recently i have been working with JSF2.0 with primefaces. we have this requirement to export PDF in our application. initially we used primefaces default dataexporter tag. but the format was simply terrible. so, i used itext to generate PDF. we have like upto 15 datatables in our app, and all of them require PDF exporting. i have created  a method called generatePDF which creates the PDF using Itext for all the tables.

```
 Interface PDFI {
 public void setColNames();
 public void setColValues();
 public void setContentHeader();

 }
Class DataEx  {
    public void generatePDF(ActionEvent event) {
        // generate pdf...
    }

}
```

consider  i have a Datatable A in the view
Datatable A ... 
bean behind this datatable..

```
Class BeanA implements PDFI {
    //implemented methods

    }

} 
Class BeanB implements PDFI {
 //implemented methods

 }
```

and behind another datatable B, i do the same thing as above .. 
so, my question here is, is this considered duplicate code ?? and also, is this the efficient way to do this. 
any help is appreciated.
thanks ina dvance

Comment: You mean that all that changes between BeanA and BeanB is the name of the class? Then yes, it would be duplicated code. You could consider then using a common super-class with that code inside

Comment: @GuillaumePolet thanks a lot for quick reply. i also have other code in both the beans, the methods that would be same are like setPdf, setColNames, setCOlVals, SetHeaderContent.

Comment: and also i must mention that i am exporting the datatable itself. i am hard coding the col header names along with their size in a Map and then passing them to a method in DataEx class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rule of thumb that I use before re-factoring duplicate code- when part of the code in one place have a bug- are you need to change the other one to? cause you probably will forget

in your case, it's look like you have duplicate code block. I'll consider add the require parameters to generatePDF so it'll do all work in one place.

Comment: hi shem, well, as i mentioned we have like 15 tables and all of them have different data in them and also the pdf header image changes for some tables and also, i am hard coding the column names in a map in the bean.

Comment: 2 quick solutions that I can think about them from the little I understand your situation- create a some PDFCreatorHelper interface, that contains all your setPdf, setColNames, setCOlVals, SetHeaderContent methods that all your databases will implement it, and pass it to the pdf generator. or create a super class for all databases with generatePDF method that uses abstract method that each database implement different. but you probably need to add some code that we'll help you.

Comment: i have edited the code in the question as u said. so, now am i still writing duplicate code thanks

Comment: haven't you say that setColNames, setColValues, setContentHeader... are different for each DB?

Comment: yes they are , i put those methods in the interface and made the beans implement that interface, thus they'd implements those methods.

Comment: so it's seem to be no duplication, or that I'm missing something =?